# differ from v differ between

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Which of these sentences is correct:

1. Pain tolerance differs from person to person

or

2. Pain tolerance differs between person to person.

Why is one preferred over the other?

Comment: (1) is correct, (2) is not, but could be changed to 'between different people' or 'between individuals'. (It's _from... to_ but _between...and_.)

Comment: You could have "between men and women" or "between John and Mary" but can't use "to".

Answer (score 0):

When someone says "person to person" they're implying general and ongoing links within a larger group.  Like "The virus spread from person to person" suggests that it's moving among a larger group, not just two individuals, though you *could* specify two individuals, like "The virus spread from Dave to Janet".

When you use "between" you need to either specify two individuals as above, or you need to use a collective term like "Pain tolerance differs between [different] people".

So your second example would be considered incorrect, but if corrected I don't think there'd be much preference between the two forms.